# How to edit the highest parent directory of a path while navigating

Tags: command-line, directory, paths, navigation, cd-command

Noob question: Let's say I'm in:

```
user@mj:~/var/www/html/mag/something/else/forever$
```

And I want to be at:

```
user@mj:/var/www/html/mag/something/else/forever$
```

Mind the `~`

I can achieve that with:

```
user@mj:~/var/www/html/mag/something/else/forever$ cd /var/www/html/mag/something/else/forever
```

Sometimes the path is lengthy, therefore, is there a way to truncate the head directory from the path? As if one step side jump?

Update:
In order not to type the whole path again.

Comment: No need for cd /, you can go directly to cd /var/www/html/mag.

Comment: you could create an alias for the command if you are frequently doing it

Comment: @mikewhatever absolutely.  I think I missed the point by that example. It's just sometimes the path is really long and I don't want to retype it all. I edited my question.

Comment: @suraj I wasn't aware that is possible. Thanks for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm... you could change `~` to `/` like this...

```
echo $(pwd | sed "s#^$HOME##")
```

(Replace `echo` with `cd` to move)

You could alias it if it's something you're often doing, due to having many similar paths in home and root

```
alias cdroot='cd $(pwd | sed "s#^$HOME##")'
```

Add to the end of your `~/.bashrc` to use any time...

Or make a simple bash function (add to `~/.bashrc`) to check whether we are in `~` and toggle from root to home and back:

```
function cdroot() {
[[ $PWD =~ $HOME* ]] && cd $(pwd | sed "s#^$HOME##") ||
cd $(pwd | sed "s#^#$HOME#")
}
```

usage demonstration:

```
zanna@toaster:~/var/log/apt$ cdroot
zanna@toaster:/var/log/apt$ cdroot
zanna@toaster:~/var/log/apt$
```

Comment: What about a condition to make it toggle between `/home` and `/`?

Comment: *'But that has more characters than'* True. I missed up by using that example.  Sometimes the paths are really long. So I wanted to know if there is away to edit part of the path.

Comment: @Ravexina I'm not even at my machine and my mum keeps telling me to stop being antisocial. I will write a function later if you haven't already XD

Comment: @MJoraid my answer should work fine for any paths where all elements apart from `~` and `/`

Comment: One more thing, I missed up again with my example. .../html/html/... was a type. That's why, get confused with paths and get a type.

Comment: I wasn't aware that I can alias a command. Thanks for the info. So I learned that I can edit the string of the current working directory on the fly and store my own frequently used commands for later use. Much appreciated. Such enlightenment.

Comment: @MJoraid most welcome! I have added a function (slightly more complicated) to toggle back and forth

Answer (score 2):

As alternative to what Zanna proposed, one can achieve same behavior with `cd "${PWD##*$HOME}"` to trim out the `~` part.

Here's a demo:

```
$ mkdir -p var/lib
$ pwd
/home/xieerqi
$ cd var/lib
$ pwd
/home/xieerqi/var/lib
$ echo  ${PWD##*$HOME}                                             
/var/lib
$ cd  "${PWD##*$HOME}"                                             
$ pwd
/var/lib
```

This approach can be combined with another parameter substitutions to check if the variable is null, i.e. we were in `~` folder and removed `~` from desired path, thus the variable is null, and therefore the function should jump to `/`:

```
$ function trimcd(){ var="${PWD##*$HOME}" ; var=${var:-/} ; cd "$var";}        
$ pwd
/home/xieerqi
$ trimcd
$ pwd
/
```

With one addition we can make it even toggle between root and home directory:

```
$ function trimcd(){ var="${PWD##*$HOME}" ;[ "$var" = "/" ] && var="$HOME";var=${var:-/} ; cd "$var";}                                               
$ pwd  
/
$ trimcd
$ pwd
/home/xieerqi
$ trimcd
$ pwd
/
$ cd ~/var/lib
$ trimcd
$ pwd
/var/lib
```

Comment: This seems better, lighter on resources

Comment: @Zanna and also implemented toggling between root and home, and still works with trimming directories. I'm off to bed now (^_^)/

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy +1 appreciated.